# Login page implemented in React generates toast : am(...).updateCurrentUser is not a function

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I have implemented a Login page with Google and Facebook on React. The code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';


firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: myKey,
    authDomain: myDomain 
})


class Welcome extends React.Component{

state ={
    isSignedIn: false
}

uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks:{
        signInSuccess: () => false
    }
}


componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user })
        console.log("user", user)
      }) 
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="Welcome">
            {this.state.isSignedIn ? 
                <div>Signed In</div>
                :
                <StyledFirebaseAuth
                uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
                firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
              />
            }

        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Welcome;
```

When I login with either of the providers a toast is generated telling me:

```
am(...).updateCurrentUser is not a function
```

The dependency of firebase as set in package.json is:

```
"firebase": "^4.10.1"
```

I couldn't find anything useful on relevant forums, and I'm a React newbie, can someone guide me what is the possible cause?

Comment: I don’t see code related to updateCurrentUser function in your question. Please share the relevant code

Comment: @Think-Twice this is a standalone file, In my router "/" is linked with the Welcome component and that's it.

Comment: @Think-Twice, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#updateCurrentUser